# How to fix create_function when swapping to PHP 7.2

Tags: php, php-7.2

I saw people helping on rewriting to anonymous function.
But I really don't know how:

> Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in /mnt/web110/c3/68/51799968/htdocs/portfolio2017/wp-content/themes/clean-photo-wp-modified/internal/includes.php on line 149

Method:

```
/**
 * Safe file inclusion
 *
 * @param $path
 */
public static function include_isolated( $path ) {
    if ( ! self::$include_isolated_callable ) {
        self::$include_isolated_callable = create_function( '$path', 'include $path;' );
    }

    call_user_func( self::$include_isolated_callable, $path );
}
```

Comment: `= function($path){include $path;};`

Comment: I wonder what the purpose is though. If it was called statically, wrapping it in another local function scope doesn't hide much more for the included script.

Answer (score 2):

```
self::$include_isolated_callable = function($path) { include $path; };
```

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Missing semicolons and please link to English manual

Comment: I did. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks alot. Now I'm one step closer.
And the best is I actualy understand what u did there :D

Comment: You are welcome :)